# How to sort a slice of a list of integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Suppose I have a list of integers as below:

```
l = [7,3,9,6,0,4]
```

The list has the odds and the evens at the two ends of it. Starting from the left the odd numbers appear first, then the evens. I want to sort the odds and the evens in place without taking the help of any other list, if possible only using sort() method. I tried the following:

```
l[0:oddCtr].sort() # to sort the odds 
l[oddCtr:].sort() # to sort the evens
```

where oddCtr is the number of odds in the list. But it didn't fetch any answer. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't fetch any answer"? `.sort()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will use in-place `list.sort()`:

```
l = [7,3,9,6,0,4]
l.sort(key=lambda k: (not k%2, k))
print(l)
```

Prints:

```
[3, 7, 9, 0, 4, 6]
```

Comment: "not k%2, k" is not clear to me. If the list contains the evens first what changes need to make to the key argument?

Comment: @SandipNath If you want even first, remove `not`. What does `not k%2` mean? `k % 2` will return `0` when `k` is even and `1` when `k` is odd. `not 0` is `True`, `not 1` is `False` - we use this information to place even values at the end of an array and odd at the beginning.

Comment: Wonderful solution.

Answer (score 1):

.sort() sorts in place...you could use the sorted() function to sort each slice and add them back together

```
l = [7,3,9,6,0,4]
oddCtr = 3
result = sorted(l[0:oddCtr]) + sorted(l[oddCtr:])
print(result)
```

> `[3, 7, 9, 0, 4, 6]`

Comment: Brilliant solution. But sorted does not sort the original list. Here are creating a new list here by concatenating the two outputs from the two sorted() methods.